# Googletest: messages are not printed on successful assertion

Tags: googletest

I'm trying to emit warnings in successful unit-tests, created with GTest.

I expect that code below prints "My warning message" somewhere:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}

TEST(suite, name)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(true) << "My warning message";
}
```

However, I don't see expected string neither in console, nor in XML files.

I've tried stepping the code in the debugger and have seen that that string is stored in the object of class `::testing::AssertionResult` created inside the  macro `EXPECT_TRUE`.

However, it is unclear what to do to make it appear.

Updating Googletest to the head of master branch doesn't help.

Comment: Just to be sure: why printing successful cases? The default approach is that the test shall be verbose only in case of errors.

Comment: To warn about still working but deprecated functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the assertions/expectations print the custom message only if the assertion *fails*. In the case of this expectation:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(true) << "My warning message";
```

it will never be triggered. You can confirm this by calling:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(false) << "My warning message";
```

using this will however make your test to fail. If you want to have messages printed when the tests is successful, you can use `SUCCEED` and a custom `TestEventListener`:

```
class SuccessListener : public testing::EmptyTestEventListener {
  void OnTestPartResult(const testing::TestPartResult& result) override {
    if (result.type() == testing::TestPartResult::kSuccess) {
      printf("%s\n", result.message());
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners().Append(new SuccessListener);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}


TEST(SuccessPrintTest, SuccessPrint) {
    SUCCEED() << "Custom message";
}
```

The output is:

```
[ RUN      ] SuccessPrintTest.SuccessPrint
Succeeded
Custom message
[       OK ] SuccessPrintTest.SuccessPrint (0 ms)
```

This will be quite verbose though if printed to the console - you may want to redirect it to a file (which would be handled by `SuccessListener`).